# Node.js TypeError: Bear is not a function

Tags: node.js, postman

I am trying to learn node.js from this tutorial: https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-restful-api-using-node-and-express-4

When I get to the Creating a Bear POST /api/bears section I get the following error from postman
[image]

It says bear is not a function and when I instantiate it `var bear = new Bear();` is when I get the error.

Here is my `bear.js`

```
// app/models/bear.js

var mongoose     = require('mongoose');
var Schema       = mongoose.Schema;

var BearSchema   = new Schema({
    name: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Bear', BearSchema);
```

And here is my `server.js`

```
// server.js

// BASE SETUP
// =============================================================================

// call the packages we need
var express    = require('express');        // call express
var app        = express();                 // define our app using express
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose   = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://node:node@novus.modulusmongo.net:27017/Iganiq8o'); // connect to our database
var Bear     = require('./app/models/bear');

// configure app to use bodyParser()
// this will let us get the data from a POST
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;        // set our port

// ROUTES FOR OUR API
// =============================================================================
var router = express.Router();              // get an instance of the express Router

// middleware to use for all requests
router.use(function(req, res, next) {
    // do logging
    console.log('Something is happening.');
    next(); // make sure we go to the next routes and don't stop here
});

// test route to make sure everything is working (accessed at GET http://localhost:8080/api)
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.json({ message: 'hooray! welcome to our api!' });   
}); 
// <-- route middleware and first route are here

// more routes for our API will happen here

// on routes that end in /bears
// ----------------------------------------------------
router.route('/bears')

    // create a bear (accessed at POST http://localhost:8080/api/bears)
    .post(function(req, res) {
        
        var bear = new Bear();      // create a new instance of the Bear model
        bear.name = req.body.name;  // set the bears name (comes from the request)

        // save the bear and check for errors
        bear.save(function(err) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            res.json({ message: 'Bear created!' });
        });
        
    });


// REGISTER OUR ROUTES -------------------------------
// all of our routes will be prefixed with /api
app.use('/api', router);

// START THE SERVER
// =============================================================================
app.listen(port);
console.log('Magic happens on port ' + port);
```

What can I  do to make bear a function?

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint and checked what the value of `Bear` is at line 47. in server.js?

Comment: I know it's really really ugly, but can you try moving your require to inside the route ? 
```var Bear = require('./app/models/bear');```
```var bear = new Bear();```
I suspect it has something to do with how require works

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, i can't comment.

Try this things:

1.Use local mongodb database and set connection string here to yours:

```
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://node:node@novus.modulusmongo.net:27017/Iganiq8o');
```

2.Set body parameter in Postman, not header.